# Docusign Not showing field which is created using docusign.Text.constructFromObject({})

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Also I am not sure about if I created fields using `docusign.Text.constructFromObject({})`

Then I need to create a custom field in the template from DocuSign sandbox?

`new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();`

Recipient view is also not showing receipt in the template

I implemented DocuSign in my angular app in the embedded view

Docusign return response success then why it's not showing fields in my app?

Here is my code:

```js
const email = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
  tabLabel: "email",
  locked: "true",
  required: "true",
  value: contractDetails.email || ''
});
```

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks! –

Comment: @MatthewRoknich I forgot to add fields in my docusign template so i created same custom field same as tabLabel name

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few properties for your Text object. When you define your Text tab, be sure to connect it to the appropriate recipient, document, and page by specifying the following:

```
text.documentId
text.pageNumber
text.recipientId
text.xPosition
text.yPosition
text.tabLabel
```

There are many more properties you can add, but you'll need these to get your tab to display properly.